# alert("Hello World"); Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I was following along a Lynda tutorial and it seemed to be working fine, I shutdown my computer and the next day, the javascript to pop up a dialog is not working when I launch the html page in Chrome, IE, Edge, Etc.

I have the most minimal html page and have it connected to my script.js file.

I've checked for most errors.

```
alert("Hello");
```

It just won't prompt it.

I've recently tried to recreate it 3-4 times, so there may be new errors.

HTML

```
<head>
    <title> Practice </title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Practice HTML and Javascript</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
alert("Hello World");
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: just checking, is the file path correct? Try putting the javascript inline instead of as a separate file.

Comment: Does your browser have enabled JavaScript?

Comment: If you are used to the chrome code inspector, you can go to the network tab and see if the request to script.js is going well. I bet is failing, and your path to script.js must be updated.

Comment: This would be a great time to get familiar with your browsers dev tools. Use the Javascript console to see if there are errors. Check the network tab to make sure you JS file is loaded properly. And Google for more helpful tips.

Comment: Is the script being served from localhost?

Comment: I've had the same problem while doing the same Lynda tutorial. What I believe it comes down to are my " marks. If I copy and paste the " from the example it works fine, if I type out the code identically it's not fine. And when I type the " next to the example the " look different. My Text Edit is set to Plain Text. It's bizarre what's happening. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2):

I got the stuff to work. Here is what I did:

- I named my files with `.html` and `.js` extensions, which were removed (maybe by default) and were not visible when viewing them in the file browser.
- I added the extensions again thinking I had made an error, so the wrong file name was being referenced in the html. It was `script.js.js` instead of `script.js` which was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your Javascript Code within your HTML file.

```
<head>
     <title> Practice </title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Practice HTML and Javascript</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello World");</script>
</body>
```

If the alert works, you probably made a mistake including your Javascript file.
If it does not work, something with your Javascript seems to bee wrong.
E.g. Javascript deactivated or Popup blocked.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you accidentally prevented the alert to be showing in this tap , try close and then reopen the tap again , also check that javascript is enabled in your browser.